# How to match a set of string in regexp

Tags: java, regex

How do I combine `ch..+` and `ch..-` in regexp effectively without having to scan separately?
And are we using `matcher` in the pattern?

My output code is like this:

```
ch01+
ch01-
ch02+
ch02-
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I combine `ch..+` and `ch..-` in regexp effectively without having to scan separately?

Use [`|` (pipe) for alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
ch..(\+|-)
```

---

> And are we using matcher in the pattern?

Depends on how you're using the regexp and the pattern. To get a concrete answer, you'll have to show some actual code, or ask a *much* more specific question.

---

**N.B.** If you want to restrict the two characters after `ch` to `0-9`, you can use `\d`, which is a [shorthand character class for `[0-9]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand):

```
ch\d{2}(\+|-)
```

Comment: This will match "ch\d{2}\+" **OR** "-". To only apply to the relevant part, you need to group alternation, i.e. `ch\d{2}(?:\+|-)` - but since these are single characters, it's much simpler to just use a character class (as in maerics answer).

Comment: Also, it might be more performant to use a non-capturing group `(?:...)` than a capturing group `(...)` since the engine doesn't need to store the matched characters.

Comment: No problem. (Apologies for the dummy edit, but stupid software wouldn't let me remove the temporary downvote without it.)

Comment: @maerics possible, but without benchmarking it's pure speculation. @Peter no apology needed, I saw your edit comment `:)`

Comment: And yeah, I agree on the non-capturing thing - no point capturing a group when it's not being used. (Of course, I'd just go for the character class option here anyway.)

Comment: Why not simply `ch\d\d[-+]` and be done with it, since that's 33% shorter and also clearer? The +50% longer solution makes me wonder what is happening. Of course only works because of the charclass alternation for the sign indicator.

Comment: @tchrist, that is an illegal chars.

Comment: thww1, since you're working with Java, you need to escape all backslashes in your string so that they get through to the regex. i.e. the `ch\d\d[-+]` regex needs to be `ch\\d\\d[-+]` in a Java string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) containing just "+" and "-" like so "`[+-]`".

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ch..[+-]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ch01+");
if (m.find()) {
  // found it...
```

Comment: Whilst the "-" character doesn't _need_ escaping here (it cannot be a range when it is last character), it's a good idea to escape it just in case, if there's any chance of more characters being added.

Comment: @Peter Boughton: Naw, just put it first. :)  You can write `[-+]` and not worry about more characters being added to the class after the plus, or before it. You only have to worry about them being added before the minus. :(

Comment: Actually, yeah, I agree with that. Better to teach people how (at least) char classes work than to unnecessarily escape things, adding noise.  Might be some situations where I'd still want `-` escaped, but this isn't one of them.